# session.getAttribute("username").toString(); ERROR OCCURS IN JSP PAGE?

Tags: java, jsp

The value in session is null. When I write this code in a JSP page, an error occurs.

```
String user = session.getAttribute("username").toString();
```

But when I write it like this no error occurs.

```
String user = (String)session.getAttribute("username");
```

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because `session.getAttribute("username")` is returning `null` which can be cast into `String` without any issue but if you try to perform any operation on `null` refefernce, you will get `NullPointerException`. Given below is a demo:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String user = (String) null;// No problem
        System.out.println(user);
        user.toString();// This will throw NullPointerException
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
null
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Main.main(Main.java:5)
```